# Add a graphic element in content type without modifying the .tpl

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I would like to add a "like" icon at the end of articles. It’s just an icon which allow the reader of the article to click on the icon and increment a counter. It’s not a social button.

For now, i can add this icon directly in page.tpl

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>

<p class="like-article-container"><span class="like-article"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></span></p>
```

It works but i was wondering if it was possible to add it directly in the content type "article" in admin without modifying the file.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify it in a preprocess_page_hook, in template.php file... but I would recommend you to stick with the tpl file approach, as you've done it there.